ModuleNotFoundError in a venv
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\videos\.venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\videos\pip.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

I tried pip install open-cv python,sudo....,and anaconda.nothing worked for me.And I also installed opencv but didnt do the rest things like extracting and all because i dont actually know how to do it .

Could you post your code?
Are you using a virtual environment?

the thing to install is opencv-python (or one of its sibling packages), into your activated venv

It's hard to answer questions like this without more details about your environment. A good start could be to provide a full list of the console commands you executed, from creating the venv to running this script.
